# django - schedule recurring task interval

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks

I'm using django_rq and rq_scheduler for some recurring jobs (like cron)

The default interval seems to be 60 seconds, but I want to change that to 600.

```
#tasks.py 
from rq import get_current_job
from django_rq import job

@job('default',timeout=-1)
def updateCheck():
    print "something"
```

(adding 'interval=600' to the decorator doesn't work)

What would be the right way to set the interval?

Comment: Please provide you package versions and complete code including imports.

Comment: Django1.8 , and https://github.com/ui/rq-scheduler/ . theres not much to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rqscheduler seems to have option to set the interval when started:

```
$ ./manage.py rqscheduler --interval=120
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using

```
from django_rq import job
```

check source code [here](https://github.com/ui/django-rq/blob/master/django_rq/decorators.py). You can see that `job` method eventually calls `job method of from rq.decorators`. If you go even deeper into [source code](https://github.com/nvie/rq/blob/master/rq/decorators.py), you can see there is no `interval` argument accepted.

https://github.com/ui/rq-scheduler/ does offer schedule inteval `scheduler.schedule()`.